# How to clone repository from branch using git2-rs?

Tags: git, rust, git2-rs

recently I wanted to copy files from a repo, in rust using `Repository::clone`, but this function does not support branches. I wanted to ask how to copy files from a branch.

I am currently using git2 version 0.17.1, and rust version 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16).

```
    let repo = match Repository::clone(repo_url, temp_dir.path()) {
        Ok(repo) => repo,
        Err(e) => panic!("failed to clone: {}", e),
    };

    println!("Cloned {} to {}", repo_url, temp_dir.path().display());
    repo.remote_anonymous(repo_url)?
        .fetch(&[branch_name], None, None)?;

    let head = repo.head().unwrap();
    let oid = head.target().unwrap();
    let commit = repo.find_commit(oid).unwrap();
    let branch = repo
        .branch(branch_name, &commit, false)
        .expect("Faild to find branch");

    let obj = repo
        .revparse_single(&("refs/heads/".to_owned() + branch_name))
        .unwrap();

    repo.set_head(&("refs/heads/".to_owned() + branch_name));

    repo.checkout_tree(&obj, None);
```

This is the code I tried. The branch has been changed. But I don't know how to swap the files from that branch with the ones that have already been copied.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation for [`clone`](https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/struct.Repository.html#method.clone), it tells you this:

> See the `RepoBuilder` struct for more information.

Then if you go to `RepoBuilder`, there's a [`branch`](https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/build/struct.RepoBuilder.html#method.branch) method.

```rs
git2::build::RepoBuilder::new()
    .branch(branch_name)
    .clone(repo_url, temp_dir.path())
```

Comment: Thank you, just some time ago when I was browsing the source code I came across RepoBuilder.